# LocalReport.Render() produces PDF with different font

Tags: .net, report, reportviewer, windows-server-2003, rdlc

I'm using the `LocalReport.Render()` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms251839%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) method to generate a PDF from an .rdlc template.

In the template I'm using **Calibri** which renders prefectly when executing from my development environment.  However when I publish the application to the server it appears the font is reverting to **Arial.**

The font is installed in `C:\Windows\Fonts` on both machines. Looking at the produced PDFs both seem to have access to Calibri:

[image]

Do you have any ideas of what may be causing this?

Comment: Did you recently install the font on the production machine?

Comment: Yes, and can see it in both C:\Windows\Fonts and in the registry.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964117/windows-fonts-not-immediately-useable-in-application-after-installing

Comment: @Stephen - Thanks very much, that link answered my question.

Comment: I am also having this problem.  For me, it displays fine when in the ReportViewer control, but then the LocalReport.Render() method produces something very different.  How can I get both to use the same font?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I simply **rebooted the server**.